# Tinder Widget Visiblility

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I used swipe_cards package for tinder like swipe but i am unable to add Text Widget That are appear during left, right and top swipe (noop, like,and super like).

```
class DatingAppDesign extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DatingAppDesignState createState() => _DatingAppDesignState();
}

class _DatingAppDesignState extends State<DatingAppDesign> {
  List<SwipeItem> _swipeItems = [];

  late MatchEngine _matchEngine;

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  List<String> _names = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "last"];

  List<Color> _colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.orange
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _names.length; i++) {
      _swipeItems.add(SwipeItem(
          content: Content(text: _names[i], color: _colors[i]),
          likeAction: () {

          },
          nopeAction: () {

          },
          superlikeAction: () {
         
          }));
    }

    _matchEngine = MatchEngine(swipeItems: _swipeItems,);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double ha = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        138 -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(

        height: ha,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
               // color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  top: Radius.circular(35.0),
                ),
              ),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
              height: ha*0.7,
              child: Center(
                child: SwipeCards(
                  matchEngine: _matchEngine,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Stack(children: [
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        color: _swipeItems[index].content.color,
                        child: Text(
                          _swipeItems[index].content.text,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
                        ),
                      ),

                      Center(child: Text("Hello World"),),
                    ],

                    );
                  },
                  onStackFinished: () {

                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: ha * 0.3,

              child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                   Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          //offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(39),
                    ),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 78, minWidth: 78),
                     child: Center(
                       child: SvgPicture.asset(
                         'assets/icons/cross.svg',
                        // color: Colors.white12,
                       ),
                     ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                         // offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(49.5),
                    ),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 99, minWidth: 99),
                    child: Center(
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/icons/heart.svg',
                       // color: Colors.white12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                       //   offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(39),
                    ),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 78, minWidth: 78),
                    child: Center(
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/icons/star.svg',
                      //  color: Colors.white12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      appBar: appbar,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNevigationDesign(),
    );
  }
}
```

I used Gesture Detector but it did not work. I read all event that under swipe_cards use same example that are on pub.dev. I am totally stuck please help me out thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that popup that comes after you do a swipe?

Comment: during right swipe you might see "like" text appear on top of image  @NagulanS

Comment: Did you try to use a Stack with the card item?

Comment: yes i used but the problem is i am not able to change the text visibility because every event that are provided by the swiper package is occurred after the swiping done but i want during swiping.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I think you are looking for snackbar in flutter.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars